# Wordpress post's code language blocks formatting is not working after importing posts from the free wordpress account

Tags: wordpress, formatting, block

I have free wordpress account and I exported my existing posts as `xml` and I imported it to my local wordpress project. All are working fine in my local project except the `[code language="bash"]...[/code]`.

Free account's post are showing like below.
[image]

After importing to local wordpres project, posts are showing like below.
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the `[code]` shortcode is from? Wordpress uses something called shortcodes, which are displayed in your content enclosed with square brackets like so: `[shortcodehere attribute="something"]`.

Shortcodes are usually converted into something else by a plugin, my guess is that your local website does not have the necessary plugin to convert it.

Comment: Yeah, may be. I did not able to find that kind of plugin which has been  installed to free wordpress account.

Comment: If you can tell me which plugins are in it, I could check which one it is. What you could also do is turn off plugins one by one and check when you see `[code ...]` instead of the code layout that it is supposed to show. Unless you are absolutely certain it wasnt caused by a plugin, then I'm afraid I don't know what is causing it.

Comment: I tried to list down the installed plugins in free wordpress account. Unfortunately they do not allow to do that. I saw automatically installed jetpack plugin by wordpress. And also there is a feature of that plugin called Extended Shortscodes by Jetpack. I did the same for my local project, but issue still there.

Comment: Are both websites of the same version of Wordpress? It seems like the [code] shortcode could be added in Guthenberg (Wordpress 5.0+), as you can see here https://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/ and here: https://en.support.wordpress.com/wordpress-editor/blocks/syntax-highlighter-code-block/ You can find your WP version in the Dashboard (button in top left) in a block called "At a glance".

Comment: In live wordpress account they have not mentioned the wordpress version under the "At a Glance" section. There is a link called "WordPress 5.2.4 Update" Under the "Wordpress Events & News". In local project version is 5.2.4. It has been mentioned under "At a Glance " section in local project.

Comment: Are you using Guthenberg or the classic editor? And are we talking about a lot of articles that use [code] tags?

Comment: If it is not too many blocks, you could re do it with the use of this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/enlighter/

Comment: I have lot of posts from 2013. That's why I searched a way to fix this. So as you say, if there is no way to fix this will have to find another similar plugin and I will have to replace this code set using mysql query.